# How to use HTML5 geolocation to give dynamic lat and long values to google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to dynamically source longitude and latitude values from browser geolocation and add them into the options array for the Google maps API. Code is shown below:

```
function initMap(){

if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        lat = position.coords.latitude;

        var options = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {lat: ${lat},${long}}
        }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
});

}
```

For some reason the options > center tag won't accept the variables I've tried to add for the lat and long values. Is there another way to do this or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is wrong here.

**Change**

```
var options = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {lat: ${lat},${long}}
        }
```

**to**

```
var options = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: { lat: lat, lng: long }
           }
```

Final code would look like...

```
function initMap() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;

                    var options = {
                        zoom: 12,
                        center: { lat: lat, lng: long }
                    }

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: Works perfectly now thanks! I was confusing myself with the string interpolation declaration of variables *facepalm*